# Round DropShadowPanel

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

How do I create a round `DropShadowPanel`? This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57232841/uwp-composition-grid-with-rounded-corners-dropshadow) provides some idea but I still got a square shadow.

This is my current try:

```
<Grid>
    <controls:DropShadowPanel
        x:Name="ShadowPanel"
        BlurRadius="10"
        ShadowOpacity="1">
        <Ellipse Width="120" Height="120" />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
    <Grid
        Width="120"
        Height="120"
        Background="DarkGray"
        CornerRadius="60">
        <FontIcon
            FontSize="50"
            Foreground="White"
            Glyph="&#xE8D4;" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Basically, I want the `DropShadowPanel` to have the same shape as the inner grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code and set `Ellipse` with color. The `DropShadowPanel` will work.

```
<Grid>
    <controls:DropShadowPanel
        x:Name="ShadowPanel"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        BlurRadius="15"
        Opacity="1"
        ShadowOpacity="1"
        Color="Black"
        >
        <Ellipse
            Width="120"
            Height="120"
            Fill="White"
            />
    </controls:DropShadowPanel>
    <Grid
        Width="120"
        Height="120"
        Background="DarkGray"
        CornerRadius="60"
        >
        <FontIcon
            FontSize="50"
            Foreground="White"
            Glyph="&#xE8D4;"
            />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ah, I am missing `Fill` for the `Ellipse`...Thanks!